# How can I pass a whitespace-delimited values file as a series of arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, files

Say that I have a file with a list of packages I want to install, separated by spaces or newlines. How can I pass that file to my package manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `xargs` command, for example:

```
cat file | xargs ls
```

Or

```
 cat file | xargs gzip -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into a an array:

```
token=($(<list.txt))
yourCommand ${token[@]}
```

If the tokens are filenames, containing spaces and separated by newlines, this will not work, because tokens are usually separated by whitespace in the shell.

Comment: “If the tokens are filenames, containing spaces and separated by newlines”, then you have to set `IFS`. http://pastebin.com/1yFufEq4

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the package names don't contain any wildcard characters (i.e. none of `\[?*`), you can use a [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution):

```
install-packages $(cat list-of-packages.txt)
```

Assuming that the package names don't contain any of the characters `\"'`, you can use [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs). Note that this redirects the input of the `install-packages` command from the package list, so it may not work if the installed requires some interactive input.

```
xargs install-packages <list-of-packages.txt
```